# Comparing Elements inside an If else condition in Jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my first time asking here on Stackoverflow,

Here is my HTML code,

```html
<div id="accordion" style="height: auto;">
  <h3>Question 1</h3>
 <div>
  <div id="q1">
 Sending messages from another user's email address is called what?  
    <ul>
 <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm optionbutton" data-optionId="option1">Spamming</button></li>
 <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm  optionbutton" data-optionId="option2">Trolling</button></li>
 <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm optionbutton answer  active clicked" data-optionId="option3">Spoofing</button></li>
 <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm optionbutton" data-optionId="option4">Pharming</button></li>
 </ul>
 </div> <!-- q1 -->
  </div>
<h3>Question 2</h3>
<div>
 <div id="q2">
    How many zebibytes are in a yobibyte?
    <ul>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm optionbutton answer" data-optionId="option1">1,024</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm optionbutton" data-optionId="option2">1,048,576</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm optionbutton" data-optionId="option3">1,000,000</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm optionbutton active clicked" data-optionId="option4">1,000,000,000</button></li>
    </ul>
   </div><!-- q2 -->
    </div>
```

And Here is my Jquery Code

```html
var q1input = 0;
var q2input = 0;
var q3input = 0;
var q4input = 0;
var q5input = 0;
    var optionele1 = $("#q1").find("button.active.clicked");
 var optionele2 = $("#q2").find("button.active.clicked");
 var optionele3 = $("#q3").find("button.active.clicked");
 var optionele4 = $("#q4").find("button.active.clicked");
 var optionele5 = $("#q5").find("button.active.clicked");
 var answerele1 = $("#q1").find("button.answer");
 var answerele2 = $("#q2").find("button.answer");
 var answerele3 = $("#q3").find("button.answer");
 var answerele4 = $("#q4").find("button.answer");
 var answerele5 = $("#q5").find("button.answer");
 if( optionele1.is(answerele1) ){ q1input = 100; }else{}
 if( optionele2.is(answerele2) ){ q2input = 100; }else{}
 if( optionele3.is(answerele3) ){ q3input = 100; }else{}
 if( optionele4.is(answerele4) ){ q4input = 100; }else{}
 if( optionele5.is(answerele5) ){ q5input = 100; }else{}
```

The question is, How should I compare the two elements in jquery? or there any wrong syntax in my code? Help please. I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the first elements in the jQuery objects to one another. For example:

```
if( $('.sel1')[0] == $('.sel2')[0] )
```

So your code should look as follows (note that there's no need for the `else` block, either):

```
if( optionele1[0] == answerele1[0] ) { q1input = 100; }
// etc.
```